# Java Error : "Could not find or load main class .ie.driver" with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Been searching for an answer and really can't find any plausible reason why this is happening.

```
java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Users\Administrator\selenium\IEDriverServer.exe -jar C:\Users\Administrator\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register/"
```

returns

> Error: Could not find or load main class .ie.driver=C:\Users\Administrator\selenium\IEDriverServer.exe

do I need to install or point to language bindings for selenium?

Comment: It looks like it somehow thinks there is a space after `-Dwebdriver`. Could be an invisible zero-width space. Try *typing* the command again. Or quote the arguments: `java "-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Users\Administrator\selenium\IEDriverServer.exe" -jar "C:\Users\Administrator\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar" -role node -hub "http://localhost:4444/grid/register/"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved with quoting all arguments as Andreas suggested.

> It looks like it somehow thinks there is a space after -Dwebdriver. Could be an invisible zero-width space. Try typing the command again. Or quote the arguments: java "-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Users\Administrator\selenium\IEDriverServer.exe" -jar "C:\Users\Administrator\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar" -role node -hub "http://localhost:4444/grid/register/" – Andreas

Comment: I had similar issue too. Thanks for the pointer of extra space in the arguments.

Comment: Yes adding double quotes surely worked.  java "-Dwebdriver.edge.driver=msedgedriver.exe" ....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't setup your manifest.mf in meta-inf or haven't specified your main class correctly in manifest.mf

In most cases, you have set your main class path into a wrong path in your MANIFEST.mf
Just re-check the main class path in MANIFEST.mf.

Or you didn't create **META-INF**:

In your IDE, under the sources root, create a new package named **META-INF**. Once that is done create a file called **MANIFEST.mf**.
Now, paste in these and modify Main-Class's value

```
Manifest-Version: 10
Main-Class: domain.something.project.Main
```

Comment: i'm running this from the commandline why would i need to have a meta-inf? i have not created any java projects. the directions given from the seleniumhq.org to start a node are here ```$ java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node -nodeConfig node1Config.json```

Answer (score 0):

### Thumb Rule

Never use `root` or `Administrator` user/login to initiate the *Test Execution* through *Selenium*.

### Solution

- Always create/login through a **`non-root`**/**`nonAdministrator`** account to execute your *Test Execution* through *Selenium*.
- Store you binaries in common location which can be accessed by any **`non-root`**/**`nonAdministrator`** users.
- Ensure that **`non-root`**/**`nonAdministrator`** users have the required permissions.
- Example:

  ```
  C:\Addison\Joseph\selenium_jars\selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar
  C:\Addison\Joseph\webdriver_variants\IEDriverServer.exe
  ```

Comment: i am not running test execution just starting the node server... would this make a difference?